# Clear selected option in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have new problem with my Select2 option. I can't clear my select box. 
As in JSFiddle I do 'select' for my data. The problem lies in the fact that I can not remove the last element, or clear the whole field in my web portal, but in JSFiddle everything looks ok. My portal gives me error "Type Error: a is null" and I don't know why.
 Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data){
    $("#mySelect").select2({
        data:data,
        placeholder: "Select options",
        templateSelection: function(val) {
            return val.text;
        }
    });
});
```

And my select:

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

The problem disappears when I use other solution but then I can not invoke the relevant data for 'templateSelection'. In this solution I create options for my select, and simple use select2 but as You can see for the field 'data.version' I have the answer "undefined" 
Code:

```
var data=[
  {id:1, text: "sample_1", version: "1"},
  {id:2, text: "sample_2", version: "2"}];

$.each(data, function(i,x){
    $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
    value: x.id,
    text: x.text
    }));
});

$("#mySelect").select2({
    templateResult: function(data) {
    return data.text + ' ' + data.version;
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/13ozkvaa/5/)

Any sugestion why this solution work in jsfiddle, but not in my portal?

Comment: You don't have variable 'a' in your code. Maybe you made misprint?

Comment: Yeah, but I got this error in jquery-2.1.3.min.js

Comment: Do you have the newest version of select2.full.min.js?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data=[{id:1, text: "sample_1", version: "1"},{id:2, text: "sample_2", version: "2"}]

$.each(data, function(i,x){
   $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
                value: x.id,
                text: x.text+" "+x.version,
                
            }));
});
$("#mySelect").select2({
  templateResult: function(data) {
    return data.text;
  }
});
```

when $ function is used to create element it can only accept html attributes of that element

Comment: This solution add 'version' to my select box and I want to avoid this. http://jsfiddle.net/13ozkvaa/8/ This example show what I want get. It works perfectly, but when I add it to portal I gets an error referred to the topic and I dont know why

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/13ozkvaa/9/ in jsfiddle I don't have any problem, but when i copy this solution to my portal, I got "TypeError: a is null" when I want to clear a select with all selected options

Comment: please update jsfiddle :) because without update I have 
my own code

Comment: $("#mySelect").select2("val", "");
use this

Comment: This solution has the same effect